# How to install dot provided by graphviz?

Tags: package-management, 11.10, 11.04, video

How can install the package? I have to do a test `dot -Tpng -o <path> <path>`
But while installing it fails.

```
$ uname -a
Linux GoogleKnockOuter 2.6.38-8-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 11 03:31:24 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ sudo apt-get install graphviz
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  graphviz-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  graphviz
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 241 not upgraded.
Need to get 341 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,102 kB of additional disk space will be used.
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  graphviz
Install these packages without verification [y/N]? y
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty/main graphviz amd64 2.26.3-5ubuntu1
  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/graphviz/graphviz_2.26.3-5ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

$ sudo apt-get update

Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty InRelease
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates InRelease
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security InRelease
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com natty InRelease
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty Release.gpg
  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security Release.gpg
  Something wicked happened resolving 'security.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com natty Release.gpg
  Something wicked happened resolving 'extras.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates Release.gpg
  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security Release
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty Release
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/main Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com natty Release
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates Release
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/restricted Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/universe Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/multiverse Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/restricted amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/universe amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/multiverse amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/main TranslationIndex
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/multiverse TranslationIndex
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/restricted TranslationIndex
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com natty/main Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty/main Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty/restricted Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty/universe Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty/multiverse Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty/restricted amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty/universe amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty/multiverse amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty/main TranslationIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty/multiverse TranslationIndex
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/universe TranslationIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty/restricted TranslationIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty/universe TranslationIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/main Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/restricted Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/universe Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/multiverse Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com natty/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com natty/main TranslationIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/universe amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/main TranslationIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/multiverse TranslationIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/restricted TranslationIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/universe TranslationIndex
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com natty/main Sources
  Something wicked happened resolving 'extras.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com natty/main amd64 Packages
  Something wicked happened resolving 'extras.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com natty/main Translation-en_US
  Something wicked happened resolving 'extras.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com natty/main Translation-en
  Something wicked happened resolving 'extras.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/main Sources
  Something wicked happened resolving 'security.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/restricted Sources
  Something wicked happened resolving 'security.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/universe Sources
  Something wicked happened resolving 'security.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/multiverse Sources
  Something wicked happened resolving 'security.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/main amd64 Packages
  Something wicked happened resolving 'security.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/restricted amd64 Packages
  Something wicked happened resolving 'security.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/universe amd64 Packages
  Something wicked happened resolving 'security.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
  Something wicked happened resolving 'security.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/main Translation-en_US
  Something wicked happened resolving 'security.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/main Translation-en
  Something wicked happened resolving 'security.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/multiverse Translation-en_US
  Something wicked happened resolving 'security.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/multiverse Translation-en
  Something wicked happened resolving 'security.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/restricted Translation-en_US
  Something wicked happened resolving 'security.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/restricted Translation-en
  Something wicked happened resolving 'security.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/universe Translation-en_US
  Something wicked happened resolving 'security.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/universe Translation-en
  Something wicked happened resolving 'security.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty/main Sources
  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty/restricted Sources
  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty/universe Sources
  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty/multiverse Sources
  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty/main amd64 Packages
  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty/restricted amd64 Packages
  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty/universe amd64 Packages
  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty/multiverse amd64 Packages
  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty/main Translation-en_US
  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty/main Translation-en
  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty/multiverse Translation-en_US
  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty/multiverse Translation-en
  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty/restricted Translation-en_US
  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty/restricted Translation-en
  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty/universe Translation-en_US
  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty/universe Translation-en
  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/main Sources
  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/restricted Sources
  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/universe Sources
  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/multiverse Sources
  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/main amd64 Packages
  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/universe amd64 Packages
  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/main Translation-en_US
  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/main Translation-en
  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/multiverse Translation-en_US
  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/multiverse Translation-en
  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/restricted Translation-en_US
  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/restricted Translation-en
  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/universe Translation-en_US
  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/universe Translation-en
  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty/Release.gpg  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty-updates/Release.gpg  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty-security/Release.gpg  Something wicked happened resolving 'security.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty/Release.gpg  Something wicked happened resolving 'extras.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty-security/main/source/Sources  Something wicked happened resolving 'security.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty-security/restricted/source/Sources  Something wicked happened resolving 'security.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty-security/universe/source/Sources  Something wicked happened resolving 'security.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty-security/multiverse/source/Sources  Something wicked happened resolving 'security.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty-security/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Something wicked happened resolving 'security.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty-security/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  Something wicked happened resolving 'security.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty-security/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  Something wicked happened resolving 'security.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty-security/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  Something wicked happened resolving 'security.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty-security/main/i18n/Translation-en_US  Something wicked happened resolving 'security.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty-security/main/i18n/Translation-en  Something wicked happened resolving 'security.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty-security/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_US  Something wicked happened resolving 'security.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty-security/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en  Something wicked happened resolving 'security.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty-security/restricted/i18n/Translation-en_US  Something wicked happened resolving 'security.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty-security/restricted/i18n/Translation-en  Something wicked happened resolving 'security.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty/main/source/Sources  Something wicked happened resolving 'extras.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty/main/source/Sources  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty/restricted/source/Sources  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty/universe/source/Sources  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty/multiverse/source/Sources  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty/main/i18n/Translation-en_US  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty/main/i18n/Translation-en  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_US  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty-security/universe/i18n/Translation-en_US  Something wicked happened resolving 'security.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty-security/universe/i18n/Translation-en  Something wicked happened resolving 'security.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty/restricted/i18n/Translation-en_US  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty/restricted/i18n/Translation-en  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty/universe/i18n/Translation-en_US  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty/universe/i18n/Translation-en  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty-updates/main/source/Sources  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty-updates/restricted/source/Sources  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty-updates/universe/source/Sources  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty-updates/multiverse/source/Sources  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Something wicked happened resolving 'extras.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty/main/i18n/Translation-en_US  Something wicked happened resolving 'extras.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty/main/i18n/Translation-en  Something wicked happened resolving 'extras.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty-updates/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty-updates/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty-updates/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty-updates/main/i18n/Translation-en_US  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty-updates/main/i18n/Translation-en  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty-updates/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_US  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty-updates/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty-updates/restricted/i18n/Translation-en_US  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty-updates/restricted/i18n/Translation-en  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty-updates/universe/i18n/Translation-en_US  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty-updates/universe/i18n/Translation-en  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

**Follow up:** Box was used in USA, and came to Europe

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by NetworkManager
empty....

$ vim /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by NetworkManager
domain telenet.be
search telenet.be
nameserver 195.130.130.129
nameserver 195.130.131.129

Works

$ http://www.graphviz.org/content/command-line-invocation
$ dot -Tpng -o <outputfile.path> <inputfile.path>
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

What happens if you try to ping us.archive.ubuntu.com?

```
ping us.archive.ubuntu.com
```

If that works, try to follow the instructions given to you and run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install graphviz
```

and then try again.

Comment: ok, there seems to be some issue with your DNS-resolver, the IP for us.archive.ubuntu.com is `91.189.88.31` - try replacing us.archive.ubuntu.com with that in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` if `ping 91.189.88.31` works :)

Comment: To install `dot`, I had to run the following: `sudo apt install graphviz`. I am leaving this here as someone else my find this helpful.